# acf fields in a jquery array

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, foreach

I create acf fields to upload logo image.

I need to get all url logo and push them in a jQuery array like this :

```
var logos = ["http://www.mylogo.com/img1.jpg", "http://www.mylogo.com/img2.jpg", "http://www.mylogo.com/img3.jpg"];
```

My ACF field :

```
    $wall_references = get_field('wall_references');
```

I wrote that :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var logos = new Array();
<?php foreach($wall_references as $wall_reference){ ?>
    logos.push('<?php echo $wall_reference['ref_logo']['url']; ?>');
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

That's print something like this in my document :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var logos = new Array();
    logos.push('http://www.mylogo.com/img1.jpg');
    logos.push('http://www.mylogo.com/img2.jpg');
    logos.push('http://www.mylogo.com/img3.jpg');
</script>
```

How to push each php URL in my array please ?

**I don't want to print my array in the console log, but directly in my document like this** :

```
var logos = ["http://www.mylogo.com/img1.jpg", "http://www.mylogo.com/img2.jpg", "http://www.mylogo.com/img3.jpg"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing one small quote mistake here, Use double quotes around instead single quotes.

```
logos.push("<?php echo $wall_reference['ref_logo']['url']; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the difficulty?

If you console.log the logos Array you have exactly what you're looking for!

Comment: I don't want to print my array in the console log, but directly in my document

Comment: well, i just printed to in my console log to quickly test it. It is getting printed in your document. The .push adds whatever you pass as a parameter to the Array (in this case logos). So your logos Array is exactly what you're describing in your question. You'll need to loop over it and then you can do whatever you'd like with the elements.

Also, note @Rishi's answer - fix the quotes!

Comment: I want to have the array directly inside my page and not in my console. Because I need to use the array with jQuery

Comment: Wrap in a document.ready, it'll execute and you have it ready in jquery. But honestly, i'm pretty confident you don't even need to do that - it should already be available - just try it!